# Replacing column values of a table with sqlite/sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table that looks like below.

```
a   b   
foo 1
doo 3
foo 4
you 5
zoo 5
doo 7
```

I want to replace/rename all the values in column A with new names

All 'foo' should be changed to 'category A'

All 'doo' and 'you' should be changed to 'category B'

All 'zoo' should be changed to 'category C'

I used replace and changed every single name previously but now the data got very big. Is there a single query where I can replace all of them?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using

**IF-ELSE CASE EXPRESSION**

```
SELECT
   CASE a WHEN 'foo' THEN 'category A'
          WHEN 'doo' THEN 'category B'
          WHEN 'you' THEN 'category B'
          WHEN 'zoo' THEN 'category C'
   END "a", b
FROM table;
```

Comment: So usually I code in python and in python I would either pass a list or a dictionary of all the values I want to replace and write a simple function. Can I do that in SQL or should I go through everything manually? Sorry. Novice here.

Comment: you could use the replace function, just add it to you query.  replace(columnname, 'oldstring', 'newstring')

Comment: if there's a lot of data you could do '%oldstring%'

Answer (score 0):

You can use an UPDATE command as follows

```
update myTable
set a = CASE a WHEN 'foo' THEN 'category A'
               WHEN 'doo' THEN 'category B'
               WHEN 'zoo' THEN 'category C'
        END
```